# vba: finding numbers not present within text

Tags: excel, vba

I have two cells within excel and they contain strings of numbers separated by comma and I need to find the numbers  which are present in cell 1 but not in cell 2. I can do text to columns and then do a vlookup but is there are more efficient way to do this?

Cell 1: 360,370,400,420
Cell 2: 400,420

Answer: 360,370

Comment: any method would be essentially duplicating a vlookup but in code (or using a keyed collection). If this is a one-off I would just use text-to-columns on cell 1 and look for them in cell 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a custom function to do this. Place in a normal code module, then you can call this on the worksheet like:

`=GetUniques(A1,B1)` and it should return the unique values.

```
Function GetUniques(ByVal cell1 As Range, ByVal cell2 As Range, Optional reverse As Boolean = False) As Variant
'compares text strings of delimited numbers in two separate excel cells
' returns unique values from cell1 by default
' to return results from cell2 instead, use optional reverse=True
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim varValues As Variant
    Dim result As String

    If cell1.Cells.Count > 1 Or cell2.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        GetUniques = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        GoTo EarlyExit
    End If

    varValues = Split(cell1.Value, ",")
    For Each v In varValues
        v = Trim(v)
        If Not reverse Then
            If InStr(1, cell2.Value, v) = 0 Then
               result = IIf(result = vbNullString, v, result & "," & v)
            End If
        Else:
            If InStr(1, cell2.Value, v) > 0 Then
               result = IIf(result = vbNullString, v, result & "," & v)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Len(result) = 0 Then result = "No matches"
    GetUniques = result
EarlyExit:

End Function
```

NOTE: This assumes the cells contain *text* formatted numbers, otherwise depending on user local, a value like `400,420` actually means `Four-hundred thousand four-hundred & twenty`

**Update**

A simple function can also do the text-to-columns thing.  Select a single cell, and then run this macro. This may overwrite data (without warning) if there is any already in the destination cells.

```
Sub SplitTextToColumns()
If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Dim cl As Range
Dim varValues As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set cl = Selection.Cells(1)
varValues = Split(cl, ",")
If  UBound(varValues) < 0 Then Exit Sub
cl.Resize(1, UBound(varValues) + 1).Value = varValues

End Sub
```

Comment: nice - but you should trim the split contents to cover the edge cases or change the v in InStr to be Trim(v).

Comment: @Cor_Blimey good call I had that in mind but got caught up in some other functionality instead like returning the error, or allowing a reverse search. Thanks!

Comment: hi David! thanks a lot, just curious to know if there is a way I can put theses unique values into separate cells

Comment: Generally speaking, it is **not possible** for a function to do this.  You would have to run a macro/subroutine instead.  I put a simple one in my revised answer.

Comment: and if you are in really annoying locales it means 400.420 :D